# mysql data gone missing after foreign key is set

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a users, merchants and factsheets table.

```
users
-----
PK - id

merchants
-----------
PK - id
FK - user_id

factsheets
---------------
PK - id
FK - (merchant_id)*
```

*I have successfully created the foreign key(FK) in factsheets referencing merchants table.
However, the FK data in factsheets disappear as soon as the FK is set.

When I try updating, it shows 0 rows is affected. Anyone knows what is going on?

Comment: Can you show us this fiddle.. sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Manage to put the codes here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b7e85/1   please take a look. Using mysql: 4.1.6

Comment: check this link.. sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f041/1 now what you wanna do

Comment: It seems that the sql workbench has some weird bug. The data is not showing in the table but when I use simple select statement to find the factsheets merchant id. It appeared.